# Using ReentrantLock in ThreadPoolExecutor to ensure thread-safe workers

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am reading JDK source code(1.8.0_05). Found that ReentrantLock is used to ensure thread-safe workers. Author just told 2 reasons.

- Reason 1:

> This serializes interruptIdleWorkers, which avoids **unnecessary
>   interrupt storms**, especially during shutdown.Otherwise exiting threads
>   would **concurrently interrupt those that have not yet interrupted**.

- Reason 2:

> It also simplifies some of **the associated statistics bookkeeping of largestPoolSize etc**.

Can anybody elaborate more details about the reason, especially Reason 1? I just don't understand the idea on design level.

P.S. How about using Collections.synchronizedSet?

Answer (score 3):

> Can anybody elaborate more details about the reason, especially Reason
>   1? I just don't understand the idea on design level.

Imagine if it were not a `ReentrantLock` but instead a concurrent set.  Also, let's imagine if 10 threads invoked `shutdown`.  Shutdown will run `interruptIdleWorkers`, so each of those 10 threads will run `interruptIdleWorkers`.

If it were a concurrent set, then all 10 threads shutting down will also interrupt every thread.  Since the collection is concurrent, then it each of those 10 threads doesn't need to wait for the others to succeed.  The result here is, as the docs said, a flood of interrupts when all you really want is 1.

You can use `Collections.synchronizedSet`, but you would have to `synchronize` on the entire collection.  This could be fine, but if you can achieve **Reason #2** with `ReentrantLock` than it is a better fit than the `synchronizedSet`.

Comment: Yeah, actually SynchronizedSet would need manual synchronization in some case, i.e. when iterating over the back set. Compared to synchronized, ReentrantLock is preferable.